# Spring Cloud Data Flow Server OAuth2 with Azure AD

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am trying to setup OAuth authentication (OpenID Connect) with Azure AD and Spring Cloud Data Flow server. Following below documentation reference but no help.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-identity-provider-azure
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-oauth2

When I push data flow server in open source cloud foundry, i get below error (if OAuth2 config is removed from application.yml, it gets deployed without issue):

*redentials/instance.key and /etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.crt
18:16:57.512: [HEALTH.0] Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
18:16:57.512: [CELL.0] Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
18:16:57.515: [CELL/SSHD.0] Exit status 0
18:17:07.588: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] Exit status 137 (exceeded 10s graceful shutdown interval)
18:17:07.857: [API.3] Process has crashed with type: "web"
18:17:07.931: [API.3] App instance exited with guid ff60a149-d91f-4d9c-90b9-661c3bb8ad0f payload: {"instance"=>"e35f4a5d-a4f0-433d-6546-82ed", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"231ab214-d841-46ba-b20f-243aeac9bbfa", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Instance never healthy after 1m0s: Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1622845027800626529, "version"=>"3a0686fb-a43a-4528-a425-21a544*

From the logs, I do not see any hint of OAuth2.0 setup is taking effect by data flow server. Here is my application.yml entries related to OAuth2 config:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authorization:
          provider-role-mappings:
            dataflow-server:
              map-oauth-scopes: true
              role-mappings:
                ROLE_VIEW: dataflow.view
                ROLE_CREATE: dataflow.create
                ROLE_MANAGE: dataflow.manage
                ROLE_DEPLOY: dataflow.deploy
                ROLE_DESTROY: dataflow.destroy
                ROLE_MODIFY: dataflow.modify
                ROLE_SCHEDULE: dataflow.schedule
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          dataflow-server:
            provider: azure
            redirect-uri: 'https://data-flow-server/dashboard'
            client-id: 977-95bc-4f3645d77f43
            client-secret: ~02K-5pf182_E-x-PWn
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
            - offline_access
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.view
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.deploy
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.destroy
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.manage
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.modify
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.schedule
            - api://dataflow-server/dataflow.create
        provider:
          azure:
            issuer-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/v2.0
            user-name-attribute: name
            access-token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/oauth2/v2.0/token
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/oauth2/v2.0/token
            user-authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdf3s-3244f65-b82d-5ec2fd32d5aa/discovery/v2.0/keys
```